# require an image in React

Tags: reactjs, image, require

in my React code this return `true`:

```
console.log(`${person.image}` === "../images/profile/mehraboon.jpg");
```

and this works:

```
return (
    <section>{<img src={require("../images/profile/mehraboon.jpg")} alt="person" />}</section>
  );
```

but this does not work:

```
return (
    <section>{<img src={require(`${person.image}`)} alt="person" />}</section>
  );
```

why?

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
console.log(`${person.image}` === "../images/profile/mehraboon.jpg");
```

person.image is not equivalent to image source & you never declare it with any variable

The standard code is your return result.

```
return (
    <section>{<img src={require("../images/profile/mehraboon.jpg")} alt="person" />}</section>
  );
```